# Creating a follow system using Django model, similar to Instagram

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to build a simple follow system for my website, but I am confused about a few things.

My **models.py** looks like this:

```
class Feed(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    rss_url = models.URLField()
    number_of_followers = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk:
            [Count number of users following self]
            [Set self.number_of_followers to counted number]
        super(Feed, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    following = models.ManyToManyField(Feed, related_name='user_following', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk:
            for feed in self.following:
                feed.save()
        super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Let me explain my code, whenever a user profile is updated, which will happen when a user follows a new feed, each of the feeds that the user follows will be saved again. As in, the save method is called.

In my Feed save method, I am going to count the number of users following self, and set it to field. However, I don't know how to actually count the users in an efficient way (problem 1)

And also, I am pretty sure that calling each Feed's save method is inefficient as hell (problem 2)

What is the efficient solution to my problems? Provided that I will be using the rest framework and serve all my data through a JSON REST API.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/GetStream/stream-django

Comment: It's getstream.io, awesome service, it'll do exactly what you want

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will check it out. But I still want to build this service on my own though, so the question is still open.